# PHP Array remove items if missing key

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array format:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 3
            [children] => Array ()
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 15
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 12
            [children] => Array ()
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 9
            [children] => Array ()
        )
)
```

I would like to remove items that do not have [children] and am having some difficulty doing so.

Help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, where `$array` is the array you want to process

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if(!isset($value['children'])
        unset($array[$key]);
}
```

This will remove all items in your array where children is not set or is `null`.  Since in your example you set children to empty arrays, you will need to use `isset()` and not `empty()`.

Comment: `empty()` should be used instead of `isset()`, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php example #1

Comment: That depends on what the desired behavior is.  `empty` will remove all values where `children` is a element, but is set to null or an empty array.  `isset` will do not remove the values if children is an empty array but is `null`, and `array_key_exists` will not remove any values where children is set to anything, even `null`.

Comment: @David I disagree.  Not only is `isset()` correct for the given example, I can't think of anywhere I would choose to use `empty()`

Comment: I misunderstood the question and deleted my answer, isset would work fine in this case :) to check whether or not an array is empty, however, `empty()` (not isset) should be used.

Comment: @David If you were the one who down-voted both correct answers, can you un-do that please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a shot and let me know what happens?

```
$myArray = array_filter($myArray, "hasChildren");

function hasChildren($node) {
    if (isset($node->children)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That worked great, just had to use $node->children because of the stdClass